# Differences in font size across safari and chrome with no css involved. Why?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have noticed that between safari and chrome the font size is different even when no css is used. The code is so simple with no styling involved but still shows major differences in size when seen in safari and chrome. There is no zoom on any browser.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

Hello

</body>
</html>
```

The link below is a screenshot of what I mean.

http://s21.postimg.org/9i82cla5z/image.png

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: yes its like that(because different browsers prefer diffrent default css settings).and you should use some css to prevent that.

Comment: The Web is not print!  Let each user's browser present your content in the way that's best for that user (hint: braille, speech) and everyone is happier..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all browsers render font and elements differently. This is why you need to create a reset.css file in order to get all browsers to a baseline and acting in the same way towards your font, ul, li etc etc.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Is there a link you could direct me to to show me how to make a reset.css file please?

Comment: http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Comment: Here you go http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/  This will give all elements a default value and then it's down to you to customise them further down the page as you wish.

Comment: Thanks! seems to have done the trick! Cheers

Comment: Glad i could help. Could you mark the answer as accept so others will benefit from it. Thanks.